# Looking up values based on whether specific columns are matching

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I'm essentially just trying to compare 4 columns. Two of these 4 columns are compared with each other. When these match a value is determined. www.xl-central.com/lookup-multiple-criteria.html

This link helped me create this formula

```
=INDEX('Nissan Colour-2018'!D4:D1048576,MATCH(1, IF('Nissan Colour-2018'!C:C1048576='Model Matching'!F2:F1048576, IF('Nissan Colour-2018'!B4:B1048576='Model Matching'!C2:C1048576,1)),0))
```

The formula does not work for some reason and I am curious to why this is occurring. What is occurring is that what I wrote is only being displayed in excel and no value is being displayed. Asking for assistance as to why my formula is not working.

```
Car worksheet

Model        Colour code     Colour description

GT-R         XBG             red
Z-Coupe      CBG             yellow
GT-R         CBG             pink
Z-Coupe      XBG             blue
GT-R         XBG             red

Day worksheet
model    Colour code     Colour description

GT-R         XBG             Red
Z-Coupe      CBG             Yellow
GT-R         CBG             Pink
Z-Coupe      XBG             Blue
GT-R         XBG             Red
GT-R         TTC             ''No match
```

The colour description for the day worksheet is determined by the colour description of the car worksheet. Since these models and colour codes for the day worksheet have matches in the car worksheet,colour descriptions are displayed for the day worksheet. However there was no GT-R model and TTC colour code combination in the car worksheet so no colour description is displayed in the day worksheet for this combination.

Comment: looks like inconsistent ranges.  Also: `C:C1048576` wouldn't work.  i would highly recommend using full columns... $F:$F, $C:$C, etc., for your search ranges.

Comment: is your goal to match the number `1` in one of your ranges defined by the if statement?

Comment: Nope, i'll give an example what i'm trying to do in the question in a moment, ok I've posted an example

Comment: Given your additional info, since there is no match, there is subsequently no index.  What were you expecting the output to be?

Comment: yeah, the data type for the cells were text so that's why the formulas were not working. They are working now but I still need to add changes to add on to the formulas.

Comment: glad that worked for you.  if you have more questions related, please post a new question so we can have 1 answer to 1 question (can be a little cumbersome, but helps with the question log).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will type this out in a weird way so you can hopefully make sense of where to place your info:

```
=index(  //standard 2 arguments
    OutputRange,
    Match(  //standard 3 arguments
        LookupVal,
        LookupRange,
        Sensitivity  //0 for exact match, 1 for "like"
    )
)
```

Take a second to name some ranges (which will store the sheet) so it is easier to make sense of your data.  If you highlight a range and start typing into the Name Box, you can store a named range, will be make this a bit easier to read to yourself, e.g.:

- Select All of column D on sheet `Nissan Colour-2018`
- Now, in the NameBox (left of the formula bar), write `Output`
- Do similar for your other lookup/match ranges, naming one `Input`.

Your final formula should look like:

```
=Index(Output,Match(B2,Input,0))
```

Where B2 is the cell reference you're trying to match.